# `Fatal error` occurred when using LAME with stdout as outfile

Tags: shell, mp3, lame

If I understand the document correctly, LAME is suposed to write to `stdout` if the `outfile` argument is set to `-`.

But when I tried this,

`lame --abr 64 --mp3input filename.mp3 -`

a `fatal error` occurred: `fatal error: can't update LAME-tag frame!`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: please include a complete cmd line with arguments that will generate your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The  [man page for lame](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lame) shows an example like

```
cat inputfile | lame -r -m m -b 24 --resample 22.05 - - > output
```

Note 2 things, there is something that is capturing the output (i.e. file `> output`)
AND (I don't understand this) , TWO `- -` chars.

SO ... ;-) ... are you just sending your output onto your terminal screen? I'm not sure that makes sense. But first, try adding that extra `-` char. (I'm used to seeing commands where you use `--` to indicate 'end of options for processing', maybe this is a variant on that'

I hope this helps.